# Change the disassembly flavor in (gdb) using Termux

Tags: debugging, gdb, disassembly

How do I change the disassembly flavor in gdb? When I try using set disassemble-flavor intel, it doesn't work. I tried set disassembly-flavor Intel as well along with set disassemble-flavor intel.

Is there a way to change it on Termux for the android? I'm very lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is quit impossible on android, as it is not a type of x86 archy.

Comment: No, android reads the assembly only in AT&T syntax, and android is not a Intel rather it's ARM... If it's on termux then radare2 is a good alternative.